# How to create a lookup relationship between two custom objects using soql

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to create lookup relationship between two custom object project and todo object but not  able to do so

This is the code to create lookup relationship between two object. It contain class two methods for create project and the create task respectively

```
public class ProjectAssignment { *//class ProjectAssignment*

     public static void createProject(){ *//method to create an object*
         Project__c pr=new Project__c();
         pr.Name='IseeIt'; //name of project
         pr.Start_Date__c= date.today()`
         pr.Description__c='This Is To Do Kind Project';
         pr.End_Date__c=date.today()+5;
         insert pr;
    }

    public static void createTask(){ *//create todo method
         //Code to fetch data*
        Project__c pr = [Select Id from Project__c]; *//query for lookup relationship between project and todo*
         ToDo__c td = new ToDo__c();
         td.Project__c= pr.Id; *//fetchhing project id*
         td.Start_Date__c=date.today();
         td.Description__c='This is the first task';
         td.End_Date__c=date.today()+2;
         insert td;

    }

}
```

> "System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"
>   because their are two project i have created  in the project object

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Project__c pr = [Select Id from Project__c];
    For this, you have to Select the query in where clause and put LIMIt 1 so that they give you only one record.
    Project__c pr = [Select Id from Project__c where name = 'IseeIt' LIMIT 1];
```